# How to query based on child dictionary in firebase? Objective C

Tags: objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, querying

[image: My User Data]

Okay so I have this User data. This is just one of the many users in my database. I want to be able to get all users that have a certain key in the "friends" dictionary. How would I do that?

I've tried

```
[[[[ref child:@"Users"]queryOrderedByChild:@"friends"] queryEqualToValue:[my uid]] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are querying equal to value with a `uid` but you have ordered by child with `friends`; the value of the snapshots inside friends is a number but you want to query equal to the key.

You can do this by adjusting your `queryOrderedByChild` to contain the `uid` you would like to check for, and query equal to `1` instead. The query child path can be made by interpolating the `uid` into a string already containing `friends/` like so `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"friends/%@", uid]`.

Comment: You sir, are a wizard. Thank you so much